# Gmail consuming GB of data

Tags: gmail, mobile-data

My Gmail app has a huge problem: only in this month it has consumed around 1 GB of mobile data, and 22GB of wifi data.
Today even though I haven't used mail at all, I have consumed 400MB of wifi data just by keeping the app installed.

I have already tried to:

- upgrade my Android to the last version
- remove all update of Gmail, and reinstall it from scratch.
- stop background data (which is a workaround and not a solution)

What else can I do?

Comment: As a temporary solution first disable it to save the data. Try other email solutions.

Comment: already done. but i'm looking for the real cause! :(

Comment: are you sure the app is not in sync to other stuff. sometimes you have photo sync and so so every photo on the device is backed up on your account.

Comment: Having the same problem now (all of the sudden). The sheer amount of data involved here is just implausible: 22GB? This *must* be due to a bug.

Comment: Actually I removed all my email prior to 1/1/2014 from my inbox, hard reset of the phone, and in 1 hour i still have used 500 mb for no reason at all (synced gmail a couple of seconds before running the test, it costed 10 MB). So yes, it must be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems the same problem these guys had solved in this 2 different 3Ds.

http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-4/310931-gmail-data-usage.html

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/gF3b9Wi-XfU

The advice given there was to reduce the number of days of messages to sync (via Gmail app settings), and avoid building up a large number of messages in Gmail inbox (archive them instead). 
Although this solutions sounds good, they never worked. 
Instead, I have solved the problem using k-9 mail.